# 'er war aufgestanden'

Tags: german-to-english, past

Do I assume correctly that the translation of

> Peter war kurz nach ihrem Zusammentreffen aufgestanden

would be, past-perfect:

'Peter had gotten up shortly after their coming together'

Comment: yes, you are correct (although it is a rather strange sentence)

Comment: @Mawg... I think Peter wasn't part of the meeting. Then it's less awkward, while still not very elegant.

Comment: @Mawg  Peter was indeed part of the meeting. Where does it get awkward and ?

Comment: With the "coming together". That is is not a phrase that a native English speaker would use for `eine Sitzung, Beschprechung, usw`  And probably the literal "stood up" (or even "risen"), rather than "gotten up" - but now I am speaking of English usage, not German - sorry

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the past perfect form of aufstehen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about this, but the sentence is indeed a bit weird. I made this answer CW, because I just stated some thoughts here.

"Er war aufgestanden" is either past perfect indicative in active voice but then the sentence actually had to be

> Peter war kurz **vor** ihrem Zusammentreffen aufgestanden.
>   Peter had stood up shortly **before** their meeting.

or it is preterite indicative in passive voice which I guess is translated as

> Peter was stood up shortly after their meeting.

I'm not a native English speaker but I guess that this translation is not good.
The German sentence is OK because you focus on the result (static passive / Zustandspassiv).

I don't really know how this is appropriately expressed in English. Technically, my translation is not that wrong, compare with

> Der Rasen war gemäht.
>   The lawn was mown.

but still it sounds wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it has to be "vor", not "nach"? Compare: "In der 10. Minute der Nachspielzeit gelang René Adler der Siegtreffer durch einen direkt verwandelten Eckstoß. Der HSV-Torwart hatte außerdem kurz _nach_ der Halbzeitpause einen Elfmeter gehalten und war damit der Matchwinner für den HSV in seiner 3. Relegation in Folge." (I just figure some sports news of May 2016 ;-) )

Comment: And do you really think that "aufstehen" kann be used in passive voice?